# Removing special characters in multiline strings Scala

Tags: regex, string, scala

Is there a way to remove special characters(`\n, \b, \t, \f, \r`) from a multi line string in Scala?

for a normal string

```
val someText = "some\nText\t"
someText.filter(_ >= ' ')       // returns "someText"
```

How do I achieve the same, in multi line string

```
val multLineStr = """some\nText\t"""
someText.filter(_ >= ' ')       // returns "some\nText\t"
```

I tried using regular expressions, couldn't remove the characters from the string.

```
val regex = new Regex("\\s")
regex.replaceAllIn(multLineStr, "")   // returns "some\nText\t"
```

Comment: `"""\n"""` is a combination of two chars, not a newline. Use `val regex = """\\[tn]""".r`

Comment: This works: `println(">some\nText\t<".replaceAll("\\s", ""))`

Comment: The triple-quoted strings are "multiline" which means that they understand the rendered new line. In other words, for every rendered new line, a `\n` character is automatically inserted. And special characters are not treated as special anymore.

Comment: @diginoise, I wanted to replace "special chars" in triple quoted strings, although it's good to know another method to replace special chars in strings, thanks

Comment: So, you are not after *removing* anything, but *defining* inside a string literal?

Comment: I was after *removing* spec chars from the string, If you had *answered* my question, I would have accepted your solution @Wiktor Stribtizew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side node, there exists [`StringContext.processEscapes`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/StringContext$.html#processEscapes(str:String):String) method which

```
  /** Expands standard Scala escape sequences in a string.
   *  Escape sequences are:
   *   control: `\b`, `\t`, `\n`, `\f`, `\r`
   *   escape:  `\\`, `\"`, `\'`
   *
   *  @param  str  A string that may contain escape sequences
   *  @return The string with all escape sequences expanded.
   */
  def processEscapes(str: String): String
```

hence

```
assert(StringContext.processEscapes("""some\nText\t""") == "some\nText\t")

StringContext.processEscapes("""some\nText\t""").filter(_ >= ' ')
// res1: String = someText
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need add interpolation to this string:

```
val multLineStr = """some\nText\t"""
println(multLineStr.toList)
println(multLineStr.filter(_ >= ' '))
```

will print out:

```
List(s, o, m, e, \, n, T, e, x, t, \, t)
some\nText\t
```

and same with `s` interpolation before the multi-line string

```
val multLineStr = s"""some\nText\t"""
println(multLineStr.toList)
println(multLineStr.filter(_ >= ' '))
```

will give your desired result:

```
List(s, o, m, e, 
, T, e, x, t,   )
someText
```